# Is "Call stack" the same as "Execution context stack" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I often see the "Call stack" in many articles.
like this: https://hackernoon.com/understanding-js-the-event-loop-959beae3ac40#ec22

[image]

But can't find the "call stack" in the ECMAScript document.
Is "Call stack" the same as "[Execution context stack](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-execution-contexts)"?

[image]

Comment: "*But can't find [a term] in the ECMAScript document.*" - that doesn't mean anything. The specification often uses weird or custom terminology. It's not supposed to be a documentation for the JavaScript programmer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Сall Stack** and **Execution Stack** are different names for the same thing. It is a LIFO stack that is used to store execution contexts created during code execution.

Wikipedia says: "This kind of stack is also known as an **execution stack**, **program stack**, **control stack**, **run-time stack**, or **machine stack**"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

One more quote: "In reality, the JavaScript engine creates what’s called an “**Execution Stack**” (also known as the “**Call Stack**”)."
https://tylermcginnis.com/ultimate-guide-to-execution-contexts-hoisting-scopes-and-closures-in-javascript/